# Оформление ссылок на подсайте

Tags: предложение, дизайн

На основном сайте ссылки выделены только цветом. При этом цвет ссылок очень плохо отличается от цвета основного текста. Особенно остро проблема проявляется когда ссылка стоит под коротким словом в середине больших предложений. Мне кажется, что новички могут этого не замечать, а если на сайт смотреть с планшета при неудачном освещении, то увидеть ссылки совсем проблематично.

Предлагаю ссылки выделять подчеркиванием (распространенная практика) или поменять их цвет на более заметный. [Например](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/), на Мете сделано и то и другое (только зачем сделано подчеркивание пунктиром не понятно).

Comment: Да и на Мете есть проблемы с цветами: [Меня огорчает цветовая схема Меты](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1395)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, цвет выделения весьма неконтрастный. насколько помню, что-то около 8% мужчин имеют те или иные нарушения цветового восприятия (у женщин на порядок меньше). я против дискриминации мужчин по зрительному признаку!

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ну вы даете :) Не думал, что этот вопрос может задеть настолько неожиданный аспект

Comment: @tutankhamun, у меня самого немного нарушено цветовосприятие (не различаю некоторые картинки в тестовых книжках у окулистов). а про дискриминацию — конечно, шутка (но про разницу между полами — правда).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, +1, по моему мнению следует убрать `text-decoration: none;` и/или задать атрибуту `link` другой цвет. Сейчас мне приходится выделять ссылки жирным, что может быть неверно воспринято.